# Are carriage returns significant in Python code?

Tags: python, indentation, carriage-return

I have the following code:

```
def find_clickable(driver, locator):
  element = None
  try:
    if locator.startswith('//'):
      element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
    else:
      element = driver.find_element_by_link_text(locator)
  except:
    raise Exception('Could not find element to click "%s"' % locator)
  if not element.is_displayed():
    raise Exception('Element to click "%s" is present but is not displayed')
  if not element.is_enabled():
    raise Exception('Element to click "%s" is present and displayed but is not enabled')
  return element
```

which works fine in a python script and also in the interactive console.

But if I enter a carriage return before `if not element.is_displayed():` in the console I get an "unexpected indent" error in the `raise` after the `if`, and in the code the function seems to end after the `except:` (it returns None)

I thought carriage returns were not significant in python code. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 4):

Carriage returns are not significant in Python code, but they are in the interactive console. If you hit enter on a blank line, it assumes you are done writing whatever class/function/loop that you are working one and tries to interpret it.